# Behaviour depicted with Composite structure(collaboration) vs. Sequence diagram

Tags: uml

When would I prefer to use collaboration defined in Composite Structure Diagram(CSD) over Sequence Diagram(SD)?

Are there some specific situations?

Answer (score 2):

Composite Structure Diagram is one of [UML Structure Diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html#structure-diagram) and is used to show static structure of the system and its parts

Sequence Diagram is one of [UML Behavior Diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html#behavior-diagram) and is used to show the dynamic behavior of the objects in a system

Comment: yes, but thanks to collaborations defined in CSD, I can depict behavior in a system with CSD too. My question was when(in what situations) I would prefer to use collaborations over showing messages passed between objects.

Comment: You "can" show behavior in CSD, but it's basic meaning is to show structure. So the answer is perfect.